# How to get the position of attribute through position()

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <p class="ABC">data</p>
    <p class="ABC">data</p>
    <p class="ABC">data</p>
    <p class="XYZ">data</p>
    <p class="XYZ">data</p>
    <p class="XYZ">data</p>
    <p class="ZXY">data</p>
    <p class="ZXY">data</p>
    <p class="ABC">data</p>
    <p class="ABC">data</p>
</xml>
```

My exception is i want create the element name with the help of attribute value then find the position of @class attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root class="xml">
    <ABC no="1">data</ABC>
    <ABC no="2">data</ABC>
    <ABC no="3">data</ABC>
    <XYZ no="1">data</XYZ>
    <XYZ no="2">data</XYZ>
    <XYZ no="3">data</XYZ>
    <ZXY no="1">data</ZXY>
    <ZXY no="2">data</ZXY>
    <ABC no="4">data</ABC>
    <ABC no="5">data</ABC>
</root>
```

My XSL CODE but i am not able to find the position of @class attribute, please look in to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xml">
        <root>
            <xsl:attribute name="class" select="local-name()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:variable name="po" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:element name="{@class}">
            <xsl:attribute name="no">
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::p/@class/[position()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making the mistake of assuming that the concept you call position (the "position of an attribute") is somehow related to what the `position()` function does. Just because they have the same name doesn't mean they do the same thing.

I would do this with `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:element name="{@class}">
        <xsl:attribute name="no">
            <xsl:variable name="CLASS" select="@class"/>
            <xsl:number count="p[@class = $CLASS]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Not tested.

Note that your question is a classic example of an XY question (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where instead of asking "How do I achieve X?", you ask "How do I use the Y function?", assuming that using Y will help you to achieve X when this is not actually the case.